# Dsmod user address tab

Tags: perl, active-directory

I have the following code:

```
my $mod_order = qx /dsmod user "CN=$user_new,$new_dn" -title "$title" -dept "$department" -company "$company" -s $dc -u $Conn_Args->{logonname} -p $Conn_Args->{pwd} 2>&1/;`
```

I need to add the following attributes to the dsmod order:

- street Address
- postal Address
- city
- state
- postal Code
- Country

As you can see I need to fill the Address tab. In order to do so I'd tried:

```
my $mod_order = qx /dsmod user "CN=$user_new,$new_dn" -title "$title" -dept "$department" -company "$company" -streetAddress "$street" -postalAddress "$postalAddress" -l "$city" -st "$state" -postalCode "$postalCode" -co "$country" -s $dc -u $Conn_Args->{logonname} -p $Conn_Args->{pwd} 2>&1/;
```

But all Address-related attributes can not be setted.

Also I tried to change the name of attributes, for example: streetAddress -> street or l -> city but does not work either...
Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dsmod does not change Address-tab attributes so I think I've to make a ps1.

**SOURCE**: [dsmod or other command to edit AD user attributes (Street, P.O. Box, City, State, Zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037215/dsmod-or-other-command-to-edit-ad-user-attributes-street-p-o-box-city-state?rq=1)